# Metal flasks with baby food in a plane

Tags: luggage, children, airport-security

Are you allowed to bring a metal flask (0.5l) with (warm) baby food inside through the security on the airport? I am flying internationally from London Luton and returning from Warsaw, Poland.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It should be Ok

> You are allowed to take baby food,
>   baby milk and sterilised water in your
>   hand baggage...
>
> You are allowed to
>   take enough for the journey. In some
>   cases this may be over 100ml. The
>   adult carrying the baby food or milk
>   may be asked to verify it by tasting.

From
[DirectGov - Air travel hand baggage rules](http://www.direct.gov.uk/en/TravelAndTransport/Publictransport/AirtravelintheUK/DG_078179)

Comment: I can confirm that I didn't have any issues with the flask.

Comment: Is this still valid ?